# PAM example of performing authentication using a custom external script?

Tags: pam, two-factor

I've heard that you can use pam_exec to call an external script, and have that external script perform the actual authentication.

Can anyone provide an example of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of examples described in [pam_exec-0.2.1/doc's README](http://www.hosowicz.com/dem/pam-exec/pam_exec-0.2.1/doc/README)